# Can't put button on image it appears under or above picture

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button on my image. However, I am facing a problem that my button appears under or above it. I've tried to solve this problem with one of the w3 examples, but still same problem. Also, I have other question how to reduce height of this picture? Because if i reduce height it does not work also.

```
<section>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">my_button</button>
        <img class="sectionImage" src="images/kendall-henderson-Pj6TgpS_Vt4-unsplash.jpg" alt="Logistics transport">
    </section>
```

```
.sectionImage {
    filter: grayscale(70%);
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Html elements take place according to the document flow. Blocks appear above each other and inline-block place besides of each other. If you want to place elements in smae place with different `z-index` then you need using `relative` and `absolute` positions which is missing in your codes. Please check here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help. Solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```css
section{
  position: relative;
}
button{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.sectionImage {
    filter: grayscale(70%);
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">my_button</button>
        <img class="sectionImage" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Logistics transport">
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
<section>
    <img class="sectionImage" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520050704800-294fd98f29e8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1296&q=60" alt="Logistics transport">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">my_button</button>
</section>
```

with this css :

```
<style>
    section {
        position: relative;
    }

    .sectionImage {
        width: 500px;
        filter: grayscale(70%);
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .btn-danger {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for different positioning. Eg: `center`, `top-right`, `bottom-left` etc. Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* Bottom left text */

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}


/* Top left text */

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}


/* Top right text */

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.sectionImage {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Bottom right text */

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}


/* Centered text */

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <button class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</button>
  <button class="top-left">Top Left</button>
  <button class="top-right">Top Right</button>
  <button class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</button>
  <button class="centered">Centered</button>
  <img class="sectionImage" src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" alt="Logistics transport">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting both tags in a container, making them both position absolute, and making the button have a greater z-index. Something like this.

`<div id="container" style="overflow:hidden; position:relative;">
    <img src="your image" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;">
<button style="position:absolute; z-index:10;top:50px; left:50px;"> TESTING TESTING 123 </button>
</div>`

From there you can edit the code for your needs and the button element should appear above the img element